# Setting VisualState Triggers in C# in Xamarin.Forms and MAUI

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, maui

For reasons not relevant here I need to set VisualState in C# rather than XAML.
However, I don't know how to change VisualState in response to a CollectionView's Selection change.

Here's the working XAML code which I'm trying to replicate in C#:

```xml
<CollectionView SelectionMode="Multiple" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel_Contacts}"
                SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="sharedModels:Showuser">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="40">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter TargetName="LabelMark" Property="Label.TextColor" 
                                        Value="Blue"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter TargetName="LabelMark" Property="Label.TextColor" 
                                        Value="Red"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Label x:Name="LabelMark"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

The way I have VisualState set in C# is as follows:

```cs
VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(LabelMark).Add(
    new VisualStateGroup() {
        Name= "CommonStates",
        States = {
            new VisualState {
                Name = "Normal",
                Setters = {
                    new Setter {
                        Property = Label.TextColorProperty,
                        Value = Colors.Blue 
                    }
                },
                StateTriggers= {
                    new StateTrigger {      
                        /* THIS IS THE QUESTION:
                        HOW DO I SET IT UP? */
                    }
                }
            },
            new VisualState {
                Name = "Selected",
                Setters = {
                    new Setter {
                        Property = Label.TextColorProperty,
                        Value = Colors.Red
                    }
                },
                StateTriggers= {
                    new StateTrigger {      
                        /* THIS IS THE QUESTION:
                        HOW DO I SET IT UP? */
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

I don't know how to set up trigger(s) for the above scenario.
It seems obvious that the trigger should be bound to the containing CollectionView's selection changed event, but I don't know how to get to it.

Comment: There is an issue about [Using TargetName reference in VisualStates in MAUI in C# (NOT Xaml)  on the github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13540). You can follow up it.

Comment: @Liyun Zhang: Thanks, I am the one who posted it...

Comment: All right, you can follow up it on the github.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Looking at the Microsoft docs for [StateTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.statetrigger?view=winrt-22621) and there is only one property that you can set. It's `IsActive` and indicates whether a trigger should be applied. So `StateTrigger` would look like this.</s>

```
new StateTrigger {      
    IsActive= true
}
```

If you are looking to bound your `VisualState` to a specific target, you should change your `Setters`. From the Microsoft docs for [Setter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.setter?view=winrt-22621). There is a property called `Target` so that you can target that element and apply the `Value` to it.

It looks like this what done on the XAML side as well, but with the property `TargetName` which does not exist.

Hope this helps.

---

Sorry I did look at the wrong Microsoft Docs. I went back and looked at the correct Docs as well as some examples from GitHub. Unfortunately the `StateTrigger` was only referenced in the XAML code.

This is the code that I was looking at if you are interested.
[XAML](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/768d9d0458dfc253fe436788afe31b9d46a198f4/6.0/Fundamentals/TriggersDemos/WorkingWithTriggers/Views/StateTriggerDemoPage.xaml)
[ViewModel](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/768d9d0458dfc253fe436788afe31b9d46a198f4/6.0/Fundamentals/TriggersDemos/WorkingWithTriggers/ViewModels/TriggerViewModel.cs)

That being said I think I managed to work out how its done from trying it out in Visual Studio. You can connect the `StateTrigger` via a `BindingContext` to your `ViewModel`. In your case I'm pretty sure in your case it would be this.

```
new StateTrigger {      
    BindingContext = new ViewModel_Contacts()
}
```

Hope that helps for real this time.

Comment: Thank you, but the doc you've referenced applies to WFP, not Xamarin or Maui.  The latter don't have the ```Target``` property, only ```TargetName```, and that one requires an ```x:Name``` attribute from XAML, which is unsupported in C#.

Comment: This doesn't quite help my particular case here, but it is a great technique to keep in mind for other similar problems.  Thank you.